# After upgrading to Spring Boot 1.4.0, NullPointerException in AbstractPlatformTransactionManager

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I have upgraded from Spring Boot 1.3.2 to 1.4.0, and now fail to start my application - 
My `BeanPostProcessor` invokes the 3d party open source Lazy Chopper, which in turns, when attempting to `getTransaction()`, fails here:

```
public abstract class AbstractPlatformTransactionManager implements PlatformTransactionManager, Serializable {

    protected transient Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    // ...
    @Override
    public final TransactionStatus getTransaction(TransactionDefinition definition) throws TransactionException {
        Object transaction = doGetTransaction();

        // Cache debug flag to avoid repeated checks.
        boolean debugEnabled = logger.isDebugEnabled(); // logger is null here
```

When I place a breakpoint right there, I can see `logger` is indeed `null`, but if it's worth mentioning that if I invoke `LogFactory.getLog(getClass())` myself right there, I do get the right logger.

It seems as if somehow my bean's invoking that method prior to the right Logger being initialized?..

Here's the full stack trace I got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:340) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:426) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:275) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.tikal.lazychopper.DefaultLazyInitializationChopperAdvice.chop(DefaultLazyInitializationChopperAdvice.java:76) ~[lazy-chopper-1.2.8.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.sapiens.bdms.core.service.impl.sign.hash.MD5StringCalculator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5747fb.getSignTypes(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sapiens.bdms.core.service.impl.sign.EntitySignCalculatorManagerImpl.postProcessAfterInitialization(EntitySignCalculatorManagerImpl.java:105) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sapiens.bdms.core.service.impl.sign.EntitySignCalculatorManagerImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$80ef4d8e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.sapiens.bdms.core.service.impl.sign.EntitySignCalculatorManagerImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91a9897b.postProcessAfterInitialization(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

I'm using the default `logback` auto configuration, no tweaks.

**Update #1:**
There's point cut defined around that method.

```
            <aop:pointcut id="transactionManagerPointcut"
                      expression="(execution(* org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(..)))"/>
```

**Update #2:**
So it seems getting rid of that aspect did the trick.. Still trying to figure out why and how to overcome this.

Here's aspect definition:

```
            <aop:pointcut id="transactionManagerPointcut"
                      expression="(execution(* org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(..)))"/>

        <aop:pointcut id="allServices"
                      expression="(execution(* com.decision..tx..*.*(..))) or (execution(* com.sapiens.bdms..tx..*.*(..))) &amp;&amp; !@annotation(com.sapiens.bdms.core.persistence.annotation.NotTransactional)"/>
        <aop:aspect ref="sessionFilterConfigurator">
            <aop:before method="setupFilter"
                        pointcut-ref="allServices"/>
            <aop:after-returning method="setupFilter"
                                 pointcut-ref="transactionManagerPointcut"/>
        </aop:aspect>
```

And here's the aspect method:

```
    @Component("sessionFilterConfigurator")
public class SessionFilterConfigurator {
    @Resource
    private Collection<FilterConfiguration> filterConfigurations;
    @Resource
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Resource
    private FiltersDisconnector filtersDisconnector;

    public void setupFilter() throws Throwable {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (AutoEnableConfig.isFiltersEnabled()) {
            for (FilterConfiguration filterConfiguration : filterConfigurations) {
                Filter filter = session.enableFilter(filterConfiguration.getFilterName());
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : filterConfiguration.getFilterParameters().entrySet()) {
                    filter.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            AutoEnableConfig.disableFilterEnabling();
            ((EventSource) session).getActionQueue().registerProcess(filtersDisconnector);
        }
    }
}
```

Still not clear as to why would that break the logger in this instance, and why only after upgrading to 1.4.0 ...

Comment: That NPE is weird. The `logger` is initialized at construction time and is not assigned again unless if the object is restored from serialization. The field is protected however so a sub-class might set it to `null`. No code does that in Spring Framework so it must be in that extension. I am puzzled as why it would do that and why it would break on update. That particular class hasn't changed at all. Can you share a sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll thanks for the prompt response. I agree. It is weird - my thought was, that no one overrides it with `null`, but rather that perhaps for some peculiar reason the `LogFactory` actually returns `null`.. Something to do with mismatches of the logger implementation?.. Does that sound like a fair assessment?.. I thought of maybe posting the dependency tree here. Do you think that could help?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll also worth mentioning, there's point cut defined for that service.  See edit above

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I have the same issue but in `AbstractRememberMeServices`. See this comment: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/763#issuecomment-63469051. Could you help me with that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the very same problem. My fault was that due to wrong pointcut definition I ended up applying aspect onto TransactionManager (I had the standard one extended). So the null logger was the one of the CGLIB's generated extended class. The real bean had its logger nicely instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't quite get what you did to get around it?..I've already figured out it most definitely related to CGLIB's generated extended class. Were you able to get around it?

Comment: I was able to work around it by wrapping around `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager` instead of `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager`. Disadvantages are clear... but I'm not sure how to get around this issue otherwise.. Not yet at least.

Comment: I corrected my aspect not to wrap around transaction manager. For all the custom stuff with transactions, I extend the standard transaction manager  instead of intercepting calls to it using aspect.

Comment: your comment is confusing me.  Are you still using an Aspect, or instead, extending Transaction Manager.  you said "corrected", but then go on to say you extend instead of intercept....which is it.  @ronif - did you figure anything more out?

Comment: Jason, I do not apply Aspect to TransactionManager anymore. However, I do use an extended TransactionManager in order to add custom logic to it (just as if aspect was applied).

Comment: I landed here when I had a similar same problem, my solution was slightly different. Not sure if it applies (and will probably not be useful) to OP. But may be usefult for others. In my case I had a class that extends AbstractPlatformTransactionManager which had a `@RefreshScope` annotation on. Removing the `@RefreshScope` annotation on that class resolved this issue.

Answer (score -2):

I also encountered this problem. In my case, I just enabled Spring aspects tooling and built the project. It worked.