# NullPointerException in AbstractRememberMeService after upgrading to Spring Boot 1.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

After upgrading from Spring Boot 1.3.8 to Spring Boot 1.4.4 I get a `NullPointerException` in `AbstractRememberMeServices` because the logger isn't instantiated successfully.

A `NullPointerException` is thrown on [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.java#L118) Line.

I write a custom `RememberMeService` which extends `AbstractRememberMeServices`. This service is registered as a bean as you can see in the following code snipped:

```
@Bean
RememberMeServices rememberMeServices(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, UserRepository userRepository, RememberMeTokenRepository rememberMeTokenRepository, RandomService randomService) {
    String key = env.getProperty("security.rememberme.key");
    RememberMeService rememberMeService = new RememberMeService(key, userDetailsService, userRepository, rememberMeTokenRepository, randomService);
    rememberMeService.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    return rememberMeService;
}
```

This error seems related to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669278/after-upgrading-to-spring-boot-1-4-0-nullpointerexception-in-abstractplatformtr). Additionally JHipster has a similar [issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/763#issuecomment-63469051).

Does anyone know why the logger isn't instantiated successfully?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I just encountered the same thing in a library's custom `RememberMeServices` impl. You may find an indication of the problem mentioned in the Spring startup logs. For instance:

> 2018-04-11 07:32:07.311  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy                    : Final method [public final org.springframework.security.core.Authentication org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.

In this case, the subclass must have some feature that requires proxying by CGLIB, such as `@Transactional` on a method. If no such features were present, CGLIB wouldn't be necessary and the subclass would behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Also got this error. When I debug, I find out the properties of *AbstractRememberMeServices* almost all null. Then I think, maybe the inject of spring not work. So I changed my code to this:

```
.rememberMe()
  .rememberMeServices(new MyRememberMeServices(env, userDetailsService, userRepo, tokenRepo))
  .and();
```

It works. But I don't understand why...

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing that out. I will check this and give you a feedback.